# Can I write rust code equivalent to the typescript code below?

Tags: function, rust, async-await, closures, function-pointers

Here is the typescript code:

```js
function gen(msg: string): () => Promise<void> {
    return async function() {
        // await any async function here ...
        await sleep(1000);
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Literally translated into rust:

```rust
fn gen(msg: String) -> async fn() -> () {
    async || {
        sleep(1000).await;
        println!("{}", msg);
    }
}
```

But the compiler does not allow such sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible (and correct) translation will be:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

fn gen(msg: String) -> impl Fn() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>> {
    move || {
        let msg = msg.clone();
        Box::pin(async move {
            sleep(1000).await;
            println!("{}", msg);
        })
    }
}
```

But it is not necessarily the best. Rust is not TypeScript, and translating code literally isn't going to work.

Comment: @FZs Because we can't move `msg` out of an `Fn` closure. Or put differently, because the function returned by `gen()` can be called multiple times.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Oh, I see!

Answer (score 0):

In Rust every closure has a unique opaque type, even identically looking ones. async adds even more uniqueness, as async blocks produce unique anonymous types that implement Future trait.

You cannot express return type of `gen` function, as you simply don't know it, compiler generates the type for you. So the solution, as @ChayimFriedman has demonstrated in his answer, is to simply state that return type implements some trait (Fn in this example), or in case of return type of returned closure, erase whatever type the async block has, by using trait objects. The `dyn impl Future` is inside Box because it has no known size, and outer Pin is necessary because returned Future type needs to have a stable location in memory in order to be executed in asynchronous runtime (e.g. `tokio` or `async-std`).

Rust's type system is quite different from that of typescript, also asynchronicity is not built into the language, but rather is implemented as various libraries, that user can opt into if necessary. Which is why direct translation between languages is not always possible.